# "This (should present/show/other) the (best/other) contrast of all"

Tags: verbs, verb-usage

While posting an [answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51707/colour-combination-for-three-buttons/51711#51711) on UX.stack (then moved to Graphic Design) I found out I wasn't sure about how to express this:

> The Go button size should be bigger and **present** the **best** contrast
>   of all since it's the primary one.

1) Is *present* used correctly? Should I have used another verb instead?
2) Is *best* the correct adjective for contrast, or would *highest* be better?
3) Is there anything else to correct in the sentence?

Comment: *High* and *strong* are the usual adjectives with *contrast*; but I suggest using *contrast* as a verb: "The *GO* button should be bigger and contrast most strongly ..."

Comment: @rewobs I agree with StoneyB. I think I might write "The Go button should be bigger and show/have the highest/strongest contrast (of all) since it's the primary one."

Comment: Great. You are both invited to post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this as:

> The Go button should be the largest element and should have higher contrast since it is the primary element on the screen.

However, your sentence structure is also fine. As noted in the comments, you can change out the word **best** for any of the following:

- most
- highest
- strongest

Your word **present** would sound more natural as just **have**. Or you could (following suggestions in the comments), use **contrast** as a verb.

To summarize, any of the following sentences would work:

> The Go button should be the largest element and should have higher contrast since it is the primary element on the screen.

> The Go button size should be bigger and have the highest contrast of all, since it's the primary one.

> The Go button size should be bigger and contrast most strongly, since it's the primary one.